# golang how to cover an interface type (always basic type) to string

Tags: go

I coded this function to cover the variable:

```
func parseValueToString(vv interface{}) string {
    switch v := vv.(type) {
    case int:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%d", v)
    case float64:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%f", v)
    case bool:
        return fmt.Sprintf("%t", v)
    case string:
        return v
    }

    panic("not support type")
}
```

but when it was `int8`,`int32`,`int64`,`float32` etc..., it will be cased to panic.
I knew that I can add `case int8`, `case int16` ..., but is there some more elegant way to do this?

I am using `go1.18`

Comment: just use `fmt.Sprintf("%v", value)`

Comment: @RahmatFathoni it works. I forgot about the `%v`, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: "Cover" or "convert"?

Answer (score 0):

you could use fmt.Sprintf(), it works like fmt.Printf except that it returns the formatted string.

You could code your function as

```
func parseValueToString(vv interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", vv)
}
```

of course you could also directly call fmt.Sprintf() instead of making a function that calls it

Answer (score -3):

> is there some more elegant way to do this?

No.

Comment: Yes. `fmt.Sprint`.

Comment: @Adrian For printing, but for the case switch nobody should recommend switching based on fmt.Sprinting with %T.

Comment: Not for printing (that would be `fmt.Print`), and not for switching. OP wants to convert an arbitrary type to a `string`. That is exactly what `fmt.Sprint` does.